# getting incremental data from Zendesk using Zenpy

Tags: python, python-3.x, zendesk, zendesk-api, zendesk-app

I have the below code from which i get the data from zendesk, The thing is that whenever i run this script i takes last 30days data.Can someone let me know what all changes i have to do to make it incremental.
Ideally this script should run twice or thrice a day(With the current script on each execution its getting last 30 days data which is unnecessary).

```
from zenpy import Zenpy
import time,datetime
import json
import psycopg2

# Connecting DB..
DSN = "dbname='postgres' user='postgres' host='localhost' password='postgres' port='5432'"
conn = psycopg2.connect(DSN)
conn.set_client_encoding('utf-8')
cur = conn.cursor()
ins_cur = conn.cursor()


script = 'DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ticket_events; CREATE TABLE ticket_events ( ID serial NOT NULL ' \
         'PRIMARY KEY, info json NOT NULL); '
cur.execute(script)
conn.commit()
print('Table dropped and recreated')

# Zenpy accepts an API token
creds = {
    'email': 'xxxxx@xxx.com',
    'token': '*************',
    'subdomain': 'xxxxxx'
}
rday = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=30)

# Default connect
zenpy_client = Zenpy(**creds)
print('Zendesk connected via zenpy')
requests = zenpy_client.tickets.events(start_time=rday,include=None)

# loop the tickets and insert to dwh
for request in requests:
    req_json = json.dumps(request.to_dict(), sort_keys=False)
    print(req_json)
    insert_query = '''INSERT INTO ticket_events(info) VALUES ( $$ ''' + req_json + ''' $$ )'''
    cur.execute(insert_query)
    conn.commit()

conn.close()
```

Below is the table structure i have defined to take values, But i feel it is not so good.I want this table to be updated incrementally with the data and delete any redundant data it have(if Any).Any suggestions on this please.

```
drop table if exists zendesk_ticket_events;
create table  zendesk_ticket_events as
   SELECT  
    CAST (info ->> 'id' as   BIGINT) as parent_id,
    CAST (info ->> 'ticket_id' as   BIGINT) as ticket_id,
    CAST (info ->> 'updater_id' as  BIGINT) as updater_id,
    CAST (info ->> 'via' as   VARCHAR (50)) as via,
    CAST (info ->> 'event_type' as VARCHAR (50)) as parent_event_type,
    CAST (info ->> 'created_at' as timestamp without time zone) as created_at,
    CAST(enrolment_info->>'via_reference_id'as TEXT)  AS via_reference_id,
    CAST(enrolment_info->>'id'as TEXT)  AS child_id,
    CAST(enrolment_info->>'assignee_id' as BIGINT)  AS assignee_id,
    CAST(enrolment_info->>'subject' as   VARCHAR (50)) AS subject,
    CAST(enrolment_info->>'requester_id'as TEXT)  AS requester_id,
    CAST(enrolment_info->>'status' as   VARCHAR (50)) AS status,
    CAST(enrolment_info->>'priority' as   VARCHAR (50)) AS priority,
    CAST(enrolment_info->>'comment_public' as   VARCHAR (50)) AS comment_public,
    CAST(enrolment_info->>'comment_present' as   VARCHAR (50)) AS comment_present,
    CAST(enrolment_info->>'event_type' as   VARCHAR (50)) AS child_event_type,
    CAST(enrolment_info->>'previous_value'as TEXT)  AS previous_value,
    CAST(enrolment_info->>'group_id'as TEXT)  AS group_id
    FROM ticket_events t, json_array_elements(t.info -> 'child_events') AS enrolment_info;
```

Below is the sample data.Can anyone cross verify the below data and let me know whether the table structure above is fine or not?

```
    {
  "child_events": [
    {
      "id": 54334560,
      "via": "Mail",
      "via_reference_id": null,
      "comment_present": true,
      "comment_public": true,
      "event_type": "Comment"
    },
    {
      "id": 54334580,
      "via": "Mail",
      "via_reference_id": null,
      "subject": "Order 10056 on 20.03.20",
      "event_type": "Create"
    },
    {
      "id": 54334600,
      "via": "Mail",
      "via_reference_id": null,
      "requester_id": 369854,
      "event_type": "Create"
    },
    {
      "id": 54334620,
      "via": "Mail",
      "via_reference_id": null,
      "locale_id": "8",
      "event_type": "Create"
    },
    {
      "id": 543342310640,
      "via": "Mail",
      "via_reference_id": null,
      "status": "new",
      "event_type": "Create"
    },
    {
      "id": 54334660,
      "via": "Mail",
      "via_reference_id": null,
      "priority": null,
      "event_type": "Create"
    },
    {
      "id": 54334700,
      "via": "Mail",
      "via_reference_id": null,
      "type": null,
      "event_type": "Create"
    },
    {
      "id": 54334740,
      "via": "Mail",
      "via_reference_id": null,
      "tags": [
        "bestellung"
      ],
      "added_tags": [
        "Orders"
      ],
      "removed_tags": [

      ],
      "event_type": "Create"
    },
    {
      "id": 54334860,
      "via": "Rule",
      "via_reference_id": 44967,
      "group_id": 2117,
      "rel": "trigger",
      "revision_id": 1,
      "event_type": "Change",
      "previous_value": null
    }
  ],
  "id": 54334540,
  "ticket_id": 159978,
  "updater_id": 369854,
  "via": "Mail",
  "created_at": "2020-03-29T18:41:22Z",
  "event_type": "Audit",
  "timestamp": 1585507282,
  "system": {
    "client": "Microsoft Outlook 14.0",
    "ip_address": null,
    "latitude": 48.3074,
    "location": "Linz, 4, Austria",
    "longitude": 14.285
  }
}
```

Comment: how are you currently executing this ? is it a single `.py` file ?? and you're manually running it ?? and what OS is it on ??

Comment: @SowjanyaRBhat Yes, it  is a single .py script. This script is a test version, i have scheduled this script via JENKINS and it is testing in MAC & Live version is in Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From where you are creating table - upto your rday variable creation - i have changed code to this :

```
create_table_sql = 'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ' \
          'ticket_events ( ID serial NOT NULL ' \
         'PRIMARY KEY, info json NOT NULL); ' # create table only if not present already

cur.execute(create_table_sql)
conn.commit()

# Zenpy accepts an API token
creds = {
    'email': 'xxxxx@xxx.com',
    'token': '*************',
    'subdomain': 'xxxxxx'
}


select_max_created = 'SELECT MAX(created_at) FROM ticket_events;' #get max-created-date of your DB 
cur.execute(create_table_sql)
row = cur.fetchone() # single row 
created_at = datetime.datetime(row[0])  
rday = created_at + datetime.timedelta(hours=1) # buffer of 1 hour
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer! But i want this script to be incremental,Only load the data greater than the max time inside the DB and i want the underlined table structure to be reviewed and instead of dropping and recreating it ,using upsert or insert .I have pasted a sample response could you please have a look at it and let me know whether the table structure i defined is fine or does it need some changes.

Comment: can you show how the data looks on your table ? few rows with dummy values . it'll be lot easier to get a picture of your problem

Comment: yes, to load data greater than max time  you can add query before creating 'rday' - with logic - `select max(created_at) from ticket_events ` - you'll get `created_at` value - use that in 'rday' variable -  may be you can add buffer of +2 hours , just to make it not miss any data.

Comment: I have mentioned the sample response and the table structure i use, Can you please have a look and let me know if it is fine or is there a better way of making this in a table format.